# Getting IDs as a list after Aggregating in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a master data frame with the following columns:

```
location_id order_id created_at pos user_id spend_amount earn_amount ref name street_address city state time date month
109936 5536 32684814 2016-06-20 17:21:56 sw?etgreen 2243440 974 900 12 - 19th + L 19th + L 1901 L St NW Washington DC 17:21:56 2016-06-20 Jun
```

I've aggregated it into a number of sub data frames

```
   AmountByUser<-aggregate(total$spend_amount, by=list(Category=total$user_id), FUN=sum)
   colnames(AmountByUser) <- c("User_Id", "Total Amount Spent")

      User_Id    Total Amount Spent
99696  3435653 46450628
207341 4821392 39621941
177899 4308353 11401622
177907 4308520 11034094
177906 4308515 8536865
177905 4308497 8324570
236885 5407939 7090316
110781 3532013 6187870
118742 3612960 4498527
236889 5407986 3441924
105507 3469230 1603637
```

How do I get the row indexes for the top n% of this subdataframe to then subset the main dataframe? End goal, have all the original columns of the main dataframe and only the rows of the top spending user_ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you do not need the row indices at all.
Simply take the top n of your aggregate and use the `%in%` operator on the full dataframe.

```
topUser = AmountByUser$User_Id[1:20]
topAllData = allData[allData$user_id %in% topUser,]
```

Comment: This takes the first 20 lines, not the top 20 values

Comment: It takes the first 20 lines of the aggregate which implies that these are the lines which hold the top 20 values.

Comment: In your shown data the aggregate is ordered (decreasing) by the "total amount spent". If it is not ordered, do a order before picking the first 20 lines. `orderedData = AmountByUser[order(AmountByUser[,2], decreasing = TRUE),]`

Comment: I had ordered it manually in R studio and not actually made a call to have it ordered. Thanks!